# Infinite ViewPager for Android (Left slide from first position not working)

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I'm implementing these two classes "InfiniteViewPager" and "InfiniteViewPagerAdapter" (You can download them from here http://angelorohit.blogspot.mx/2014/08/an-infiniteviewpager-for-android.html).

These clases are nearly perfect, the only problem is that sliding from the first position to the left doesn't work, it only works if you slide from the first position to the right, then to the left again to return to the first position and then left again. I've tried to fix this, but the workflow of the base clases is so convoluted I can't figure out what do I need to change. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Please elaborate your question and show us what have you tried so far.

Comment: I've tried to edit the listeners, basically the InfiniteViewPager calls a method move the position of the fragments when you reach the first and last fragment but for some reason this doesn't work in <Scenario 1> It doesn't matter how I edit the InfiniteViewPager class, the app always crashes

<Scenario 01>

STEP 01: *Can't Move* <- Position 1

<Scenario 02>

STEP 01: Position 1 -> Position 2

STEP 02: Position 1 <- Position 2

STEP 03: *Move Succesful* <- Position 1

Comment: So, no one can help me?